# Por que o album de fotos do facebook retorna um array vazio?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk

Estou usando o Facebook SDK com o Laravel 4. Preciso retornar as imagens do algum do usuário que fizer o login via Facebook.

Quando eu utilizo o usuário, o qual é o administrador do APP no Facebook, as imagens e os albuns são retornados normalmente.

Porém, quando tento fazer isso com um usuário qualquer, que não seja administrador, é retornado um array vazio.

O código que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

```
$session = new FacebookSession(Session::get('facebook.token'));

$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/me/albums',
    ['fields' => 'name,photos.limit(20){source},id']
);

$response = $request->execute()->getGraphObject();

$imagesOfAllAlbums = [];

foreach ($response->asArray() as $albuns) {

   foreach ($albuns as $k => $album) {

    if (empty($album->photos)) continue;

    foreach ($album->photos as $images) {

        foreach ($images as $image) {

            if (empty($image->source)) continue;

            $imagesOfAllAlbums[$album->name][] = $image->source;
        }
        }
   }
}

count($imagesOfAllAlbums); // 0
```

No primeiro caso, isso retornaria isso:

```
[
   'Nome do Album' => [
         'imagem_1.jpg',
         'imagem_2.jpg',
    ]
]
```